# How do I turn this into a json?

Tags: json

https://bgp.potaroo.net/cidr/autnums.html

I want to turn this into a json, the format I want would look like:

```
{
    "AS1": "LVLT-1, US",
    "AS2": "UDEL-DCN, US",
    "AS3": "MIT-GATEWAYS, US"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? The data seems trivial enough to be scraped - it's anchor tag's content + the text next to it. The challenging part is the huge input size but that might not matter in your use case?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Haven't tried anything yet, just didn't know where to start..

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is using `lynx` (the Unix command) to convert the page into a text file and then parse it with the programming language of choice.